# How can I add an ad to play automatically after the player dies

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads

I want the video ad to play automatically after the player dies , ( the ad can be skipable) . Can somebody help me with a script for this?The game is in Unity and is 2d. This is the code for player dies

```css
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
        {
            isDead = true;
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GameController.Instance.Die();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide explaining it step by step
https://unity3d.com/services/ads/quick-start-guide